# ignoring whitespace parsing xml

Tags: xml, xcode, swift2

I have been having problems while parsing from an xml file, I have however discovered that it is the whitespace in my xml file that is causing the problem.

If I put all my xml items in one huge line it works perfectly (nightmare to work with), however if there is any whitespace it doesn't.

My question is..... is there a way to get xcode to ignore the whitespace?

This works...

```
<item>item 1</item><item>item 2</item><item>item 3</item><item>item 4</item>
```

This doesn't as xcode adds the whitespace...

```
<item>item 1</item>
<item>item 2</item>
<item>item 3</item>
<item>item 4</item>
```

This isn't my actual code (obviously) just a representation.

I have looked at apple's documentation but it made my brain hurt!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try by trimming white space and new line character sets.

Comment: Please post an [mcve] that illustrates this problem.  Include the error message that you're getting.  If I had to guess, I'd bet your multi-line version has leading space before the XML declaration, but why should we be guessing?   Post an [mcve].

Comment: As HarshIT says, make use of the string method `.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())`. The following post should be helpful for you: http://rshankar.com/blogreader-app-in-swift/

Comment: What API are you trying to parse the XML with?

Comment: I got it sorted Jeremy(as per above comment), thanks anyway. I cant tick the answer as complete as it was a comment.